# ASP.NET visual studio 2013 login control in tool box always show error in code behind

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, login-control

I'm using Visual studio 2013 and I'm developing an ASP.NET Web application. I dragged and dropped login control from tool box. Its form name is 'Form1', Login ID is 'log1'. I tried to access the text box in the login form named 'UserName' and 'Password' with 'log1.UserName' and 'log1.Password' . I always get this error, 'the name 'log1' doesn't exist in the current context. What should I do? Can anyone help? Thanks in Advance!

My code behind file home.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }
    static int count = 0;
protected void log1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if (log1.UserName == "Admin" && log1.Password == "Admin")
    {
        Response.Redirect("Adminhome.aspx");
    }
    else if (YourValidationFunction(log1.UserName, log1.Password))
    {
        Session["User"]=log1.UserName;
        e.Authenticated = true;
        Response.Redirect("userhome.aspx");
        log1.TitleText = "Successfully Logged In";
    }
    else
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
        count++;
        if (count >= 3)
        {
            count = 0;
            Session["User"] = log1.UserName;
            Server.Transfer("MainPage.aspx");
        }
    }
}
SqlConnection strConnection = new SqlConnection("server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=honeypot;integrated     security=true;");
    private bool YourValidationFunction(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        bool boolReturnValue = false;
        String SQLQuery = "SELECT UserName, Password FROM Register";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, strConnection);
        SqlDataReader Dr;
        strConnection.Open();
        Dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (Dr.Read())
        {
            if ((UserName == Dr["UserName"].ToString()) & (Password == Dr["Password"].ToString()))
            {
                boolReturnValue = true;
            }
        }
        Dr.Close();
        return boolReturnValue;
    }
    protected void lnkRegis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("AdUserAcc.aspx");
    }
}
```

Home.aspx:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <asp:Login ID="log1" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="2">Log In</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="log1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="log1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me next time." />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                        <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="log1" />
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:Login>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the TextBox controls using FindControl:

```
TextBox txtUserName = (TextBox)log1.FindControl("UserName");
TextBox txtPassword = (TextBox)log1.FindControl("Password");
```

Comment: Still log1 shows the error.  Its log1 that has error. Not username and password. Even the log1 in ur code shows error.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your [@Page directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ydy4x04a(v=vs.100).aspx) on top of page which **i can not see in your markup** of aspx page.

You should specifically Check for the

1) `Inherits` attribute, The inherits attribute should match to the partial class name in your code behind file, which inherits from System.Web.UI.Page class.

2) `CodeBehind` attribute, should match to the code behind file which you are coding in.

For example if your page name is Default the @page directive should look like following at it's minimum

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"
 Inherits="WebApplication.Default" %>
```

In your case the above should be

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs"
 Inherits="YourWebApplicationName.Home" %>
```

For more detailed information on the @Page directive and it's all attributes i would suggest you to see this [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ydy4x04a(v=vs.100).aspx).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added @Page Directive. And it is correct.@Devjosh

Comment: I have already added the @Page Directive. I just missed it when adding the code here

Comment: is your problem solved regarding login control was not accessible from code-behind file, have you checked the inherits attribute, make sure the class name spelled correctly in code-behind file as well as your @page directive. can you edit the question and place the page directive in question.

Comment: The spellings are correct, they are auto generated files, when i created new webform. And i have manually checked them also

Comment: I dont know what that is. But only thing that is with log1 is a red underline and error: "log1 doesnt exist in current context

Comment: This has to do with markup definitely, optionally try clean + build